# API Event Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I am not able to fire API Event in my journey.
Its a very simple Journey (API Event >> Wait >> Email >> Exit).

Have already configured Contact Builder by linking by DE to the Contacts.

Am using the below REST call. Getting this error -

> {
>     "message": "Runtime Error. Retry this action. Contact Global Support if the issue persists",
>     "errorcode": 30000,
>     "documentation": ""
>   }

```
{  
"ContactKey":"ContactID_444444",
"EventDefinitionKey":"APIEvent-886b05f3-bc2f-bbbb-5fc4-a0ad5928432a",
"EstablishContactKey":true,
"Data":{  
  "FName":"Rick",
  "LName":"Porter",
  "EmailAddress":"abc@gmail.com",
  "SubscriberKey":"ContactID_444444",
  "Phone":"3173173171"
      }
}
```

Endpoint that I am using is

> https://www.exacttargetapis.com/interaction/v1/events

What am I missing?

Comment: What endpoint are you using? Can you confirm that the `EventDefinitionKey` matches the Event Definition Key Event Key used by the Entry Source? These typically start with a `ContactEvent` prefix, but perhaps you have created your own custom key?

Comment: Hi @EliotHarper - Yes, the EventDefinitionKey matches. I have used the newly introduced API Event Source and for those, it starts with APIEvent

Comment: I've tested your request payload using the API Event Source and it works for me. You've mentioned that you have linked the DE to your Contact model. Note that the Event Source DE does not need to be part of your Contact model. To isolate this, please can you try removing that DE relationship in the Contact model first and trying the request again?

Comment: Thanks Eliot. It worked for me too. Stupidly, I was using wrong Client ID/Secret.

Comment: @Maneesh can you tell me where do you find the contactKey ?

Comment: Contact Key here is the subscriber key that you want to assign to the subscriber